# ng-click not sending updated value

Tags: angularjs

I have following code:

```
<div class="input-field col s3" ng-repeat="data in content.data">
<input class="updatable mcq"
        ng-disabled="!viewMode" 
        type="checkbox"
        id="mcq{{data.surveyPropertyId}}"
        ng-click="updateMCQ(data.surveyPropertyId,data)"
        ng-model="data.value"/>
<label for="mcq{{data.surveyPropertyId}}">{{data.name}}{{data.value}}</label>
```

```
$scope.updateMCQ = function(surveyPropertyId,newValue){
                                console.log(newValue);
                            }
```

problem is that it in updateMCQ function it shows right value of data.value

but if i trigger a click event on this input element it shows previously selected value. for example if checkbox is checked it would send false.

Also {{data.name}}{{data.value}} is evaluating and changing correctly as check / uncheck this element

What can be the problem

UPDATE:

I have found the problem and its a silly one. when I call $('.updatable.mcq.ng-dirty').trigger('click') or for change, it actually changes and now the element value has been changed.!!!.

Now can anyone guide me on how to create a custom directive which would act like an event same as click or change in angularjs?

Comment: please add the `updateMCQ` function.

Comment: Another way to do this would be to have an isSelected variable in your data object. Something like this; {surveyPropertyId: 1, value: 'something', isSelected: false}

Comment: adding isSelected variable isnt feasible here because i dont know in advance how many checkboxes would be present and dont want to iterate through them all. I am using $('.updatable.mcq.ng-dirty').trigger('click') to call updateMCQ function

Comment: it does not matter, iterate through the array and add an isSlelected variable and set it to false

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/fxp6bJsc9uDJB5eOgiZ7?p=preview, check this link;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem and its a silly one. when I call $('.updatable.mcq.ng-dirty').trigger('click') or for change, it actually changes and now the element value has been changed.!!!.

Comment: it not much great to use `jquery` with angular, try to use the `angular-directives`  such as `ng-change` and `ng-model` for these kinds of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ng-change** like:

```
ng-change="updateMCQ(data.surveyPropertyId,data)"
```

Comment: checked that. didnt helped

Comment: please add fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` and it will work for you as said by @Jenny.

Here is the code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div class="input-field col s3" ng-repeat="data in content">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.value" ng-change="updateMCQ('data.surveyPropertyId',data)"> click and check console

{{data}}

</div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.content =[{ value: false },{ value: false },{ value: true }]
    $scope.updateMCQ = function(surveyPropertyId,newValue){
              console.log(newValue);
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above code.**

[**Check this demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fxp6bJsc9uDJB5eOgiZ7?p=preview)